# Bash: delete most files in directory

Tags: regex, bash, directory, filenames, rm

I have a directory full of mostly postscript files which I'm trying to erase most: Namely those who don't have `000100`, `000110`, `000120` or `000200` on the second place in their name. I want to retain those.

Here is an excerpt from the directory:

```
0091_000100_0000_0000_0001_000000__66_5_32_6_9_82856598585_60_3560351294_L_40_1_52_9_42_97_58_53.ps
0091_000110_0000_0000_0002_000000__66_5_32_6_9_82856598585_60_3560351294_L_40_1_52_9_42_97_58_53.ps
0091_000120_0000_0000_0002_000000__66_5_32_6_9_82856598585_60_3560351294_L_40_1_52_9_42_97_58_53.ps
0091_000200_0000_0000_0002_000000__66_5_32_6_9_82856598585_60_3560351294_L_40_1_52_9_42_97_58_53.ps
0091_000300_0000_0000_0002_000000__66_5_32_6_9_82856598585_60_3560351294_L_40_1_52_9_42_97_58_53.ps
0091_000310_0000_0000_0002_000000__66_5_32_6_9_82856598585_60_3560351294_L_40_1_52_9_42_97_58_53.ps
0091_000320_0000_0000_0002_000000__66_5_32_6_9_82856598585_60_3560351294_L_40_1_52_9_42_97_58_53.ps
0091_000330_0000_0000_0002_000000__66_5_32_6_9_82856598585_60_3560351294_L_40_1_52_9_42_97_58_53.ps
0091_000400_0000_0000_0002_000000__66_5_32_6_9_82856598585_60_3560351294_L_40_1_52_9_42_97_58_53.ps
0091_000410_0000_0000_0002_000000__66_5_32_6_9_82856598585_60_3560351294_L_40_1_52_9_42_97_58_53.ps
0091_000420_0000_0000_0002_000000__66_5_32_6_9_82856598585_60_3560351294_L_40_1_52_9_42_97_58_53.ps
0091_001120_0102_0000_0003_000000__66_5_32_6_9_82856598585_60_3560351294_L_40_1_52_9_42_97_58_53.ps
0096_000100_0000_0000_0001_000000__85_5_2__2_37732144298_48_1790154593_L_52_26_17_77_41_43.ps
0096_000110_0000_0000_0002_000000__85_5_2__2_37732144298_48_1790154593_L_52_26_17_77_41_43.ps
0096_000120_0000_0000_0002_000000__85_5_2__2_37732144298_48_1790154593_L_52_26_17_77_41_43.ps
0096_000200_0000_0000_0002_000000__85_5_2__2_37732144298_48_1790154593_L_52_26_17_77_41_43.ps
0096_000300_0000_0000_0002_000000__85_5_2__2_37732144298_48_1790154593_L_52_26_17_77_41_43.ps
0096_000310_0000_0000_0002_000000__85_5_2__2_37732144298_48_1790154593_L_52_26_17_77_41_43.ps
0096_000320_0000_0000_0002_000000__85_5_2__2_37732144298_48_1790154593_L_52_26_17_77_41_43.ps
0096_000330_0000_0000_0002_000000__85_5_2__2_37732144298_48_1790154593_L_52_26_17_77_41_43.ps
0096_000400_0000_0000_0002_000000__85_5_2__2_37732144298_48_1790154593_L_52_26_17_77_41_43.ps
0096_000410_0000_0000_0002_000000__85_5_2__2_37732144298_48_1790154593_L_52_26_17_77_41_43.ps
0096_000420_0000_0000_0002_000000__85_5_2__2_37732144298_48_1790154593_L_52_26_17_77_41_43.ps
0096_000430_0000_0000_0002_000000__85_5_2__2_37732144298_48_1790154593_L_52_26_17_77_41_43.ps
0096_000440_0000_0000_0002_000000__85_5_2__2_37732144298_48_1790154593_L_52_26_17_77_41_43.ps
0096_000450_0000_0000_0002_000000__85_5_2__2_37732144298_48_1790154593_L_52_26_17_77_41_43.ps
0097_000100_0000_0000_0001_000000__81_5_46_2_48_2146991211_65_1953946853_L_44_6_72_1_58_71_77_49.ps
0097_000110_0000_0000_0002_000000__81_5_46_2_48_2146991211_65_1953946853_L_44_6_72_1_58_71_77_49.ps
0097_000120_0000_0000_0002_000000__81_5_46_2_48_2146991211_65_1953946853_L_44_6_72_1_58_71_77_49.ps
0097_000200_0000_0000_0002_000000__81_5_46_2_48_2146991211_65_1953946853_L_44_6_72_1_58_71_77_49.ps
0097_000300_0000_0000_0002_000000__81_5_46_2_48_2146991211_65_1953946853_L_44_6_72_1_58_71_77_49.ps
0097_000310_0000_0000_0002_000000__81_5_46_2_48_2146991211_65_1953946853_L_44_6_72_1_58_71_77_49.ps
0097_000320_0000_0000_0002_000000__81_5_46_2_48_2146991211_65_1953946853_L_44_6_72_1_58_71_77_49.ps
0097_000330_0000_0000_0002_000000__81_5_46_2_48_2146991211_65_1953946853_L_44_6_72_1_58_71_77_49.ps
0097_000400_0000_0000_0002_000000__81_5_46_2_48_2146991211_65_1953946853_L_44_6_72_1_58_71_77_49.ps
0097_000410_0000_0000_0002_000000__81_5_46_2_48_2146991211_65_1953946853_L_44_6_72_1_58_71_77_49.ps
0097_000420_0000_0000_0002_000000__81_5_46_2_48_2146991211_65_1953946853_L_44_6_72_1_58_71_77_49.ps
0097_000430_0000_0000_0002_000000__81_5_46_2_48_2146991211_65_1953946853_L_44_6_72_1_58_71_77_49.ps
```

This is what I'm trying to get:

```
0091_000100_0000_0000_0001_000000__66_5_32_6_9_82856598585_60_3560351294_L_40_1_52_9_42_97_58_53.ps
0091_000110_0000_0000_0002_000000__66_5_32_6_9_82856598585_60_3560351294_L_40_1_52_9_42_97_58_53.ps
0091_000120_0000_0000_0002_000000__66_5_32_6_9_82856598585_60_3560351294_L_40_1_52_9_42_97_58_53.ps
0091_000200_0000_0000_0002_000000__66_5_32_6_9_82856598585_60_3560351294_L_40_1_52_9_42_97_58_53.ps
0096_000100_0000_0000_0001_000000__85_5_2__2_37732144298_48_1790154593_L_52_26_17_77_41_43.ps
0096_000110_0000_0000_0002_000000__85_5_2__2_37732144298_48_1790154593_L_52_26_17_77_41_43.ps
0096_000120_0000_0000_0002_000000__85_5_2__2_37732144298_48_1790154593_L_52_26_17_77_41_43.ps
0096_000200_0000_0000_0002_000000__85_5_2__2_37732144298_48_1790154593_L_52_26_17_77_41_43.ps
0097_000100_0000_0000_0001_000000__81_5_46_2_48_2146991211_65_1953946853_L_44_6_72_1_58_71_77_49.ps
0097_000110_0000_0000_0002_000000__81_5_46_2_48_2146991211_65_1953946853_L_44_6_72_1_58_71_77_49.ps
0097_000120_0000_0000_0002_000000__81_5_46_2_48_2146991211_65_1953946853_L_44_6_72_1_58_71_77_49.ps
0097_000200_0000_0000_0002_000000__81_5_46_2_48_2146991211_65_1953946853_L_44_6_72_1_58_71_77_49.ps
```

My try so far works but is somewhat unpractical:

```
#!/bin/sh
for f in *.ps; do
   case $f in
      (0091_000100*.ps|0091_000110*.ps|0091_000120*.ps|0091_000200*.ps)
         ;;
      (*)
         rm -- "$f";;
   esac
done
```

I have to write every start of the filename I want to keep. One problem: The script doesn't match the `0096_*` and `0097_*` files and all the others omitted for readability. The format of the filename is always the same up to the double underscore. The values in the number groups might change.

Is there a way to match for the second group? My experimentation wasn't successful so far.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like `ls *.ps | awk -F_ '$2 < 100 || $2 > 200'` might be the list of files you want to delete. After verifying that,

```
rm $(ls *.ps | awk -F_ '$2 < 100 || $2 > 200')
```

As long as  no file has whitespace or glob characters in its name. (If they do, use xargs)

Answer (score 2):

I like using find for best performance when dealing with a large count of files.

This regex should yield the same results:

`find . -type f  -name '*.ps' |egrep "000[12]{1}[012]{1}" |xargs rm -f`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming a directory has only regular files...

```
ls *.ps | egrep -v '^[0-9]{4}_000100_|^[0-9]{4}_000110_|^[0-9]{4}_000120_|^[0-9]{4}_000200_' | xargs rm -f
```